# would have + participle v.s. would + verb

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I can't grasp the difference between their usages. Could you explain them over the following examples?

- It was half past five. Dad would have finished work.
- It was half past five. Dad would finish work.

I can't perceive any difference. But if I guess, in first sentence, the speaker is not sure concerning finish of the work. Yet, on the second, he is sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the person thought "It is half past five. Dad has finished work [by now]".

The second example doesn't make sense without something being added.

*It was half past five. Dad would finish work soon* or *at six*, for example.